# React component children error with typecript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I started learning react with typescript a few days ago and I am getting this error

```
    /home/sotiris/Github/ecommerce-merng-platform/admin/src/components/DashboardHOC/DashboardHOC.tsx
TypeScript error in /home/sotiris/Github/ecommerce-merng-platform/admin/src/components/DashboardHOC/DashboardHOC.tsx(118,22):
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & { children: string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal; disableGutters?: boolean | undefined; fixed?: boolean | undefined; maxWidth?: false | ... 5 more ... | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<ContainerTypeMap<{}, "div">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.  TS2769

    116 |       <main className={classes.content}>
    117 |         <ErrorAlert>
  > 118 |           <Container>{children}</Container>
        |                      ^
    119 |         </ErrorAlert>
    120 |       </main>
    121 |     </div>
```

Dashboard.tsx

```
const DashboardHOC: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = ({ children }) => {
   ...
    {children}
   ...
}
```

Error.tsx

```
const Error: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = ({ children }) => {
   ...
    {children}
   ...
}
```

What Am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
React.FC<React.ReactNode>
```

This means that your props will be a react node, which is never correct. Props are a plain object which you can define any number of properties on. Some of those properties might be react nodes, but the object itself will not.

If you're trying to specify that `children` is a ReactNode and there are no other props, then React.FC already does that and you can do:

```
const DashboardHOC: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
```

Or if you prefer to be explicit that there are no other props:

```
const DashboardHOC: React.FC<{}> = ({ children }) => {
```